# FLEX: widget (text input) with text suggestions?

Tags: apache-flex

is there any flex widget providing text suggestions such as google search suggestions ? I just need the popup window showing the text,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several available at [Adobe Exchange](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm), I don't know of an official one. I searched for Autocomplete within Flex, here are [my search results.](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?searchfield=autocomplete&search_exchange=15&search_category=-1&search_license=&search_rating=&search_platform=0&search_pubdate=&Submit=Search&num=10&startnum=1&event=search&sort=0&dummy_tmpfield=).

Comment: Cool, which one did you choose?